# plantuml in docker, gitlab nginx configuration doesnt work

Tags: nginx, gitlab, plantuml

plantuml runs on docker.
The port had to be changed from 8080:8080 to 8088:8080.
it works at `http://localhost:8088/uml`, doesnt work  at `http://localhost:8088/plantuml`

gitlab recommends the following configuration

```
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location /-/plantuml { \n rewrite ^/-/(plantuml.*) /$1 break;\n proxy_cache off; \n proxy_pass http://localhost:8088/plantuml; \n}\n"
```

due to the situation above, I've tried without success the following (uml instead plantuml)

```
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location /-/plantuml { \n rewrite ^/-/(plantuml.*) /$1 break;\n proxy_cache off; \n proxy_pass http://localhost:8088/uml; \n}\n"
```

Do you have any recommendation how to fix this?

edit to add:
as recommended I tried

```
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location /-/plantuml { \n rewrite ^/-/plantuml(.*) /uml$1 break;\n proxy_cache off; \n proxy_pass http://localhost:8088/uml; \n}\n"
```

with the result of a call to `https://gitlabdomain.com/uml/AxfDWj2tBq3CoKoPWR1Io8ZDoSa70000` which was a 404

Could the http vs https be relevant here?

Comment: Try this ``nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location /-/plantuml { \n rewrite ^/-/plantuml(.*) /uml$1 break;\n proxy_cache off; \n proxy_pass http://localhost:8088/uml; \n}\n"``

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and this seems to work:

```
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location /-/plantuml { \n rewrite ^/-/plantuml(.*) $1 break;\n proxy_cache off; \n proxy_pass http://localhost:YOUR_PORT/uml; \n}\n"
```

In other words, I eliminated `plantuml` from the URI and simply pass the rest of the URI to the backend.